CDF for min(x, 1-x)

Find the cumulative distribution function of $Y=\min(X,1-X)$

if:
a) $X \sim U[0;1]$
b) $$F_X = \begin{cases}0 & : x < 0 \\ x^2 & : 0\leq x < 1 \\ 1 & : 1\leq x \end{cases}$$.
My solution:
a) for any $0<a<\frac{1}{2}$: Pr($Y>a$) = Pr($\min(X, 1-X) > a$) = Pr($X > a, 1-X>a$) = Pr($a<X<1-a$) = $x |_a^{1-a}$ = $1-2\cdot a$
Then Pr($Y \leq a$) = $2 \cdot a$ and Y $\sim U(0; \frac{1}{2}]$
b) for any $0<a<\frac{1}{2}$: Pr($Y>a$) = ... = Pr($a<X<1-a$) = $x^2 |_a^{1-a}$ = $(1-a)^2 - a^2 $ = $1-2 \cdot a$
and further steps and results are the same (If I haven't made a mistake in my reasoning anywhere). And Y $\sim U(0; \frac{1}{2}]$, although I expected the same distribution for Y as for X in b), but in the semiinterval $(0; \frac{1}{2}]$, as it seems more intuituive.
What could be the reason for the same answers? Is this an accident or a feature of the distribution of the $\min$ function?

First, note that the PDFs of the two variables in $[0, 1]$ are $f_a(x) = 1$ and $f_b = 2x$.
As you've noted in your calculations, this is a consequence of the fact that $\int_a^{1-a} f(x) \; dx = F(x) |_a^{1-a}$ is the same when $f$ (resp. $F$) is taken to be either PDF (resp. CDF). This, in turn, is a consequence of the rotational symmetry of the PDFs around $(0.5, 1)$. Because of this, $\int_a^{0.5} (f_b(x) - 1) = -\int_{0.5}^{1-a} (f_b(x) - 1)$, and hence $\int_a^{1-a} (f_b(x) - 1) = 0$, implying that the integrals from $a$ to $1-a$ are the same for $f_a(x) = 1$ and $f_b(x)$.
It is easy to construct other PDFs that will have this same property. For example, $$f_c(x) = \begin{cases}
  2 x^2 + 1/2 & 0 \leq x \leq 0.5 \\\
  -2(x-1)^{2}+3/2 & 0.5 \leq x \leq 1
\end{cases} $$

